# How do I convert only specific parts of a string to uppercase in Python?

Tags: python, string

So I am writing a function that takes in a string input (ex: `abcdefg`) and a shorter portion of that input (ex: `cde`) and searches for it within the first longer string.

How do I make it so that only that second portion is capitalized in the first string?

Ex:

- Input 1: abcdefg
- Input 2: cde
- abCDEfg

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 20):

```
def foo(str1, str2):
    return str1.replace(str2, str2.upper())
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> a = "abcdefg"
>>> b = "cde"
>>> c = b.upper()
>>> a.replace(b,c)
'abCDEfg'
```